# Full Screen Layered Videos Using Z-Index

Tags: css, html, video, z-index

I'm currently working with a project where I need to layer 2 possibly 3 videos over top of each other. I've been able to do this with Flash as well as video using the html5 video tag and Z-indexes, but when I hit F11 to go full screen all I can see is the first video ie the first layer that is supposed to have the layered videos on top of. The criteria of my project requires that upon f11 my project to launch with the layers as they were built. I tried giving my top 2 videos a super high z-index which I read would work, but no dice.

I made a fiddle that has 1 video set as a background and 2 positioned over top. Again this works until I hit f11 to go full screen. It seems to just be rendering the bottom or background video over top of all z-indexes.

https://jsfiddle.net/lukeslytalker/j1ssLqvj/2/

HTML

```
<div id="over">
<video autoplay loop>
    <source src="minion1.mp4"></source>
</video>
</div>
<div id="over2">
<video autoplay loop>
    <source src="minion2.mp4"></source>
</video>
</div>
<video autoplay loop id="myvideo">
<source src="152_0030.mp4"></source>
</video>
```

CSS

```
body { 
margin:0; 
padding:0; 
overflow:hidden; 
}
#over {
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
z-index: 10005; 
}
#over2 {
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
z-index: 10000; 
}
```

Javascript

```
<script>
var elem = document.getElementById("myvideo");
if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
elem.requestFullscreen();
} else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
} else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
}
</script>
```

Comment: There is a reason why SO has a rule that prevents fiddle links being posted when no code is present in your answer — it is because we want authors to understand the code they are posting and reduce it for us, if possible, instead of simply dumping a link without giving an adequate description of the code and what it does. Please do not skirt this rule.

Comment: Sorry? I'm not sure what you are talking about. This must have been viewed before I had my code up.

Comment: @Terry while the code wasn't in the question and probably should have been the OP does understand the code and did create a small example which is what the fiddle was. He also gave a pretty clear description of the problem I thought.

Comment: Yes, I am referring to your [initial incomplete question](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/28833315/1) before you edited it.

Comment: Listen I'm just looking for some clarity. There's a reason I don't post here much because there is a lot of bravado and rather than answering questions more questions just get asked. I think I was pretty straight forward with my question. I provided my code. Has anybody worked with layered videos and z-indexes before?

Comment: For one, high "z-indexes" are bad, mainly b/c it's not necessary. If you go over a `5` `z-index`, then you need to reformat your `HTML`. Additionally, perhaps your `width` and `height` need to be set on the containing elements (`divs`). Your `body` element should have `position:relative;` as well, since the `html` element will be above that

Comment: @RobScott That view on z-indices is pure opinion. Absurdly high values for z-index are okay because they are *valid*. It's just tabs vs spaces all over again. Many developers follow practices of incrementing values by 5 or 10 so that it's easy to keep track of and still leaves space for extra items in-between.

Comment: @TylerH - not much to keep track of if you don't go over `4` or `5`, which is why i said one would need to reformat their `HTML`. I redesign other's websites all the time, and it's plain annoying attempting to find out and re-configure crappy `CSS`. You're right, it's an opinion, but there's no need to go over the small limit. Clean javascript can be used for those `z-index` elements, such as fade in/out sliders, etc.  ;)

Comment: @RobScott There are definitely cases where you need to go over some arbitrarily small limit imposed by a random developer on the web :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you already have the z-index part figured out, if I understand correctly, you want the videos to be full width?

This can be done using the `background-size` style.

```
video{ 
background-size:cover;
/*vendor prefixes*/
-moz-background-size: cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
-ms-background-size: cover;
/*sizing*/
width:100%;
margin:0 auto;
display:block;
}
```

This targets every video, saying `background-size:cover;`, *"Scale the background to be as large as possible so that the background is completely covered by the background image [video]."*

`background-size` is supported in: 
- Chrome : 4.0+
- IE9
- Firefox : 4.0+
- Safari : 4.1+
- Opera : 10.5

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j1ssLqvj/5/)

Comment: Woohoooo that did it. Thanks so much for your help. I knew I was pretty close. Sorry about getting snippy as well. I've just had issues posting on this site where rather than get answers I get more questions by people who know more about what it is I'm asking about than I do. I'm looking for answers by standing on the backs of giants. I try to explain myself to the best of my abilities. I feel like some times people just want to show off how smart they are. Thanks for the straight forward advice. It was very helpful. :)

Comment: No worries man, I know the feeling, sometimes it's harder to explain what you're trying to accomplish, especially if you're still learning something. The general sense is that they want to know that you have a basic idea of what your code that you wrote is supposed to be doing, then describe what it should be doing. That way more knowledgeable peers can chime in with what they see wrong. Having reduced code is a lot easier to skim through then giving them a full 300-line HTML file. Glad I could help!

Comment: You sure did. Thanks again.

Comment: Oh I should also mention, I ran my above code w/o the added JS Function and it worked all the same. So I would say it's safe to say that you won't need the extra JS for it.

Comment: I just tried the same. You're right. This was in an effort to make this work. It doesn't look like I need it now. Thanks.